# Action IDs, ACT URLs not working

Tags: logout, action

I'm using v2.8.1, and I'm having problems with ACT URLs. They don't seem to be working. The issue came up with DevDemon Channel Images, but I think it's related to Action IDs in general, as the logout is not working either. ACT URLs redirect to the homepage.

They work on my local site, which is a mirror of the remote and has the same .htaccess file.

I'm at a loss. I've tried adjusting the htaccess, and removing it, and clearing the cache, all with no luck. I'm hosted at hostgator, here's the htaccess file:

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /

        # Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
        RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/systemname/.* [NC]
        RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]

        # Directs all EE web requests through the site index file
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

     AddType text/x-component .htc
```

Has anyone had any similar problems, or an approach for debugging? Thanks in advance for any help.

Update: When I add index.php to the ACT URL, it works... I'm assuming that I can update the HTACCESS file to get this working, but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the .htaccess line you're looking for:

> RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^(ACT=.*)$ [NC]

This is how my typical .htaccess looks like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# add the www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^alchemyviral.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.alchemyviral.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# Remove the trailing slash to paths without an extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !=POST
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1 [L,R=301]


# Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^(ACT=.*)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5})$
RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay in getting back to this - this solved my problem, it's working now. Thank you!!

Comment: doesn't the `^` make it so it only works when action is the first query string argument?